# How to select edges for ripping without selecting enclosed faces?

Tags: edit-mode, faces, edges, selection-tools, seams

I need to rip apart an object at its seams. Typically, I would do so by selecting a seam, selecting similar edges, and ripping the vertices apart. However, some objects have several seams that form the edges of a single triangular face; both similarity selection and manual edge selection have the same effect of selecting those faces enclosed by those seams, causing the error:

> Cannot rip selected faces

when subsequently attempting to rip the selection.

I believe that this means that I need to deselect these faces before performing the rip operation. But how do I select the seams of these objects *without* selecting *any* faces between them?

Comment: @moonboots Ripping vertices doesn't work in _Edge Select_ mode either if the selected edges build a face.

Comment: oh ok i must have misunderstood something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess instead of ripping vertices with <kbd>V</kbd> what you want is to split the faces along the selected edges, which is done with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> > *Split* > *Faces By Edges*, or from the menu: *Mesh* > *Split* > *Faces by Edges*.

Comment: Thank you, this *almost* works, but I would amend your answer to split faces by edges instead (Mesh > Split > Faces by Edges). Doing split-by-selection does something else which is definitely not the intended behavior of ripping with zero offset!

Comment: @zeyonaut I don't know what you exactly want to do, but first of all when I use _Mesh_ > _Split_ > _Selection_ there is no offset... apart from that, the question says "at its seams" and I was going for a more general solution to fit this phrase: you can put seams on a mesh that do not necessarily fully enclose faces. If you used _Faces by Edges_ you will always separate complete faces, even if some of their edges are not selected.

Comment: My intent was to rip the vertices so that each vertex corresponds to a single UV coordinate (the seams are generated from UV islands). However, selecting the seams and performing a selection-split has the effect of duplicating the selected edges (and faces, in this case) and leaving the original selected edges untouched, which... well, I'm really not sure what use cases would exist for this operation, to be honest.

Comment: @zeyonaut Oh, now I understand how you want to split it up. Yes, _Faces by Edges_ might work better this way. In a way this duplicates edges, too - if the edges on the seams were not duplicated, you could not move the face separately. But I see what you mean. The _Selection_ split separates complete faces as well if all their edges are selected, but it doesn't split adjacent faces if they are both selected. "Open" edges are duplicated because otherwise you could not separate them while leaving the faces intact - but sure, that's not what you want. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @zeyonaut The use cases for the _Selection_ operation are quite simple: splitting faces is not limited to things like separating UV islands with seams. If you select e.g. some connected faces on a sphere and want to separate them from the rest of the mesh, it is easy to select them in _Face Select_ mode. If you do this, all their edges are selected. If you now choose to split _Faces by Edges_, the faces would not only be separated from the rest of the sphere, but each face would be separated individually from all the other selected faces.